# How to check whether resize and move events are actually finished in air windowed application

Tags: actionscript-3, air

i tried using RESIZE and MOVE events from nativewindowBoundEvents. but they are constantly being called, as long as event is happening.
i just wanted to know, when event is done. user actually finish moving or scaling application..

> _myApp.nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.MOVE,winPosChangeHandler,false,0,true);
>   _myApp.nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZE,winSizeChangeHandler,false,0,true);

Comment: Have you tried combining these with a MOUSE_DOWN/UP listener? If those events fire before and after the move and resize listeners you could assume the even is complete on mouse_up

Comment: thanks, thats exactly, i am currently solving this. i thought may be some other decent way , that is hidden from me ...